# VM cannot communicate with host on a given port

Tags: virtual-machine, firewall, port-forwarding

I'm doing some sort of school project where i have to make my vm (using virtualbox for hosting the vm) communicate with my host pc using port 6969.

The problem is that even after all the things I tried to open this particular port, the vm still says connection refused.
I'm using bridge adapter, the vm is a linux one, and my host is manjaro.
I cannot do any sudoer thing on the vm, it's mounted on an iso given by the school that is sure to be working fine (no one besides me had any problem with it) but is not giving me any admin rights.

Ssh connection are fine though, here are a few commands I ran on the vm :

```
$> nc -zvw10 192.168.1.40 6969
nc: connect to 192.168.1.40 port 6969 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

```
$> nc -zvw10 192.168.1.40 22
Connection to 192.168.1.40 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

And my opened and flushed iptables on host side :

```
$> sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Tried setting new rules on iptable using

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6969 -j ACCEPT
sudo systemctl restart iptables
```

Tried using Gufw (gui for ufw) for setting new rules, no more success.

Any idea on things to try would help me so much.
Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
I need to communicate with the host using an executable made in C that seems to be using connect() to send data, so I cannot chose a way to communicate here, I just know it's using port 6969 to connect to the given ip.(I'm using host local ip as target for the connection)

Comment: You show port 22/ssh worked. So... How do you know it worked? You only show a connection succeeded, but was it actually the host's ssh daemon, or something else somewhere else? I.E., verify the full communication path is succeeding from end to end. Do a real ssh in, not a `nc` connection, and run a `uname` or `hostname` command to ensure you're connected to the host. If you are, then look at the connection path, and see if you can see anything that is different than when you try port 6969. I will, of course, assume you have verified that port 6969 is even available on the host.

Comment: ssh will accept a port number in the configuration and/or one can be specified on the command line.

Comment: If ssh is working then sftp will allow you to send/receive files (securely).

Comment: @C.M. sorry for late reply, I did try to connect using ssh, and it worked just fine, could connect to host pc, the hostname and uname were both correct. Not sure how I'm supposed to check the connection path ? Using traceroute ?
And about checking if port 6969 is open, I just allowed all incoming connection on any port, isn't it enough ? I tried adding a rule for opening port 6969 (as described above) but nothing happened

Comment: @JeremyBoden the problem is that I have to send the file using a C executable file, so I cannot chose how it works.

Comment: `traceroute` should not matter in this case, and the problem is probably a a different level/layer than traceroute operates, but the concept is similar. The are many tools to help, possibly different tools at different stages in the comm path. One check, _from_ the machine that is supposed to be listening on port 6969, can you connect via loopback to itself? Can you run the daemon on the host, and have it connect successfully via the host's loopback? Try to narrow down and isolate _where_ the problem is.